# Writing data in an xml file via xmlwriter PHP

Tags: php, xmlwriter

Hello my script is creating xml file with two elements in it but im not able to adding next element(name = item) to created xml file. can anyone help me?? :) can i load file enter items add one item and save file???

```
<?php
  $content = file_get_contents('http://evidujem.sk');
  preg_match('#<br /><b> (.*?) užívateľov</b>#', $content, $match);
  $pocet = $match[1];

  $writer = new XMLWriter();
  $writer->openMemory();
  $writer->setIndent(true);
  $writer->setIndentString('  ');
  $writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
  $writer->startElement('items');
  $writer->startElement('item');
  $writer->writeAttribute('aktualny_datum', date('j.n. Y'));
  $writer->text('pocet registrovanych:' . $pocet);
  $writer->endElement();
  $writer->endElement();
  $writer->endDocument();

  $filename = 'pocet.xml';
  $file = $writer->outputMemory();
  file_put_contents($filename,$file);

  ?>
```

output in the xml file shoul be:

```
<items><item date="aktualny datum">pocet registrovanych</item>
       <item>...</item>
</items>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you need. Can you please post a sample of the input file `pocet.xml`, together with what you want to change in it, and what the resulting file should be after saving? Then what would you want to add later?

Comment: <items>
   <item date="aktualny datum">pocet registrovanych</item>
   <item>...</item>
   <item>...</item>
</items>

Comment: @user3626182 Code does little help in a comment.

Comment: PLEASE help me.... can i load file enter items add one item and save file???

Comment: This began as a simplexml question but is now XMLReader.  SimpleXML is probably easier to use...

Comment: i just want make it work doesnt care how (only one condition is i cant use libraries) Please help me... Im lost